# How to format abd get empty time with it with moment when it doesn't exist in string?

Tags: ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have a use case where I have variable data in the following formats. When the string doesn't have time, the format object formats it with `12:00:00` => `12:00 am`.
Well technically, the constructor that passes only a date IS instantiating it with a time, 12:00:00, even though it is implicit.

### Example

1. `'2021-02-12'`
2. `'2021-02-12T6:00'`
3. `'2021-02-19T18:00'`

### Code

```
const date = moment("2021-02-12");
date.format("h:mm a"); // 12:00 am
```

### Expected

I'd like to know if that is possible that moment format the time with the empty string `""` when time is not available in the data. e.g.

```
    const date = moment("2021-02-12");
    date.format("h:mm a"); // ""
```

Comment: You are trying to format Date is hour format. What are you expecting ?

Comment: yes, I am trying to format it in hour or any format which includes hour formatting. e.g. "MM-DD-YY h:mm a" < I expect that the hour formatting is empty string rather than 12:00 am